# MATLAB neural nets: trainbfg problems when using a custom performance function

Tags: neural-network, matlab

I have written my own custom performance function, that is a cross entropy function with some modifications, called augmented cross entropy function.

My performance function itselft is a sum of two functions: cross entropy function F and a penalty function P, the formula given below:

[image: Performance function] 
[image]

where *B* and vectors *e1* and *e2* are just some constants and `w` is a weight matrix (`i` for hidden layer neurons, `j` for input layer neurons).

I've implemented dy and dx derivatives, not being very sure about the dx derivative (where x is a result of getx function - it holds all weight and bias information). I assumed that the dx derivative of my performance function for a weight `wij` will be equal to derivative of the penalty function:

[image: Derivative dx]

Then I started training my neural network with *trainbfg* function and found out it does not learn anything. Message was "Line search did not find new minimum". From trainbfg description:

> Each variable is adjusted according to the following:   X = X + a*dX;
>   where dX is the search direction.  The parameter a is selected to
>   minimize the performance along the search direction.

It turned out that parameter `a` is always calculated as 0 by the default search function, *srchbac* (line search). I assume it has something to do with my performance function being wrongfully implemented, because when I set *mse* as the performance function, `a` is calculated properly.

What is the reason of the problems during locating a new minimum by the `srchbac` function? Just to know where I should look for as for a second day I found nothing.

Edit:

The x vector consists of input-hidden connections' weight values first and then the rest biases and weights. I calculate the dx derivative of the weights vector with the following formula:

```
res = 2 .* E1 .* b .* W ./( 1 + b .* W.^2).^2  + 2 .* E2 .* W ;
```

and the rest of the values I set to 0 (so that `res` has the same length as the x vector).

Comment: you could also try asking this on: http://stats.stackexchange.com/